# CRON JOB scheduling while checking the other scripts status

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a scenario where I have three shell scripts in which 2 scripts should start simultaneously and as soon as the first two have finished the third script should start.
Ex: 
Test1.sh and Test2.sh should start parallely and when both the scripts are completed successfully Test3.sh should start. Could someone help me with this scenario on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this syntax (regardless of cron context) :

```
test1.sh & test2.sh ; test3.sh
```

I'm not certain cron accepts a `;` in its command. If not you could instead use this :

```
(test1.sh & test2.sh) && test3.sh
```

That however requires the `(test1.sh & test2.sh)` to return a 0 return code for `test3.sh` to be executed.
It looks like `(command1 & command2)` will return the result of `command2` (I tried `(exit 1 & exit 0) ; echo $?` and it echoes 0, while `(exit 0 & exit 1) ; echo $?` returns 1.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. The below syntax worked.
test1.sh & test2.sh ; test3.sh

Comment: @SurenderKumar You're welcome, glad to help. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.